# Find each RegEx match in string

Tags: c#, regex

id like to do something like

```
foreach (Match match in regex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(match.ToString());
    }
```

Thanks for any help...!

Comment: Can you show an example input & output?

Comment: For those of us who are too lazy to look it up, and do not know: RegularExpressions is in the System.Text namespace.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a [`RegEx.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) method:

```
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(myStringToMatch))
{
  MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
}
```

To get the matched substring, use the [`Match.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx) property, as shown above.

Comment: @kojoma - Have you supplied a parameter to the `Matches` method?

Answer (score 10):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx)

```
  string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";    
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);    
  string sentence = "Who writes these notes?";

  foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence))
  {

     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                       match.Value, match.Index);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You first need to declare the string to be analyzed, and then the regex pattern.
Finally in the loop you have to instance `regex.Matches(stringvar)`

```
string stringvar = "dgdfgdfgdf7hfdhfgh9fghf";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(stringvar))
{
    MessageBox.Show(match.Value.ToString());
}
```