# c# regularexpression how to find two records in the string

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

ok i am building up my email templating engine and trying to break up some of the text between {{{   }}} from my this text

```
 var matches = Regex.Matches("sdfsdfsdf{{{GetServices:Pilotage}}}sdfsdfsdf dfsdf{{{GetServices:Berth Fee}}}sdfdsf{{sss", "{{{(.*)}}}");
```

how can i parse this string so i get this as a result array. i have been trying different things but with no avail. how can i achieve this

```
1)GetServices:Pilotage

2)GetServices:Berth Fee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the matches.

```
var input = "sdfsdfsdf{{{GetServices:Pilotage}}}sdfsdfsdf dfsdf{{{GetServices:Berth Fee}}}sdfdsf{{sss\", \"{{{(.*)}}}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\\{\\{\\{(GetServices:[^{]*)\\}\\}\\}");
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Groups.Count == 2)
    {
        result.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 'If the match is successful, the first element in the collection contains the Group object that corresponds to the entire match. Each subsequent element represents a captured group,  if the regular expression includes capturing groups.'

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt (although maybe not optimal) should work if you force it to be non-greedy:

```
{{{(.*?)}}}
```

Just add a `?` after the `*`.

Comment: I like this answer more because it actually addresses the problem with the pattern used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
(\{{3}\w*\:[\w\ ]*\}{3})+
```

**Edit**:

For obtaining the value, see answer:
[Find each RegEx match in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525181/find-each-regex-match-in-string)

Comment: Note: match will include `{{{` and `}}}`, move parens inside to match contents only

Comment: @CS - If it doesn't match the pattern with `{{{` and `}}}`, if you have, i.e. `"asdasd:asdas{{{Something:GetStuff}}}asdasd` wouldn't it match the preceding text with that pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern would be `"\{{3}(.+?)\}{3}"` or `"\{{3}(.*?)\}{3}"`. It depends on your need if the string in between is optional or required.